AWS Device Farm NodeJS Appium unable to run due to APK error
I'm trying to set up AWS device farm and Appium to run a simple set of tests for a react native project.
Everything works fine locally but I'm having real problems getting it set up on AWS.
There doesn't seem to be any real documentation or even a decent tutorial on how to set this up either which is slightly worrying but I think I've patched together most of it from the limited resources available.
The error from my test runs is:
ERROR webdriver: Request failed with status 500 due to unknown error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. 

Original error: Cannot read the manifest from '/tmp/devicefarm-workspace/execution-nfv4_k3j/uploads-d6ac72wc/app-oo1gwle6.apk'. Update build tools to use a newer aapt2 version. 

Original error: W/ziparchive(17000): Unable to open 'badging': No such file or directory

A few google searches lead me to a possible aapt2 issue so I have updated all my build tools and when running:
aapt2 dump badging /path/to/my/app.apk there are no errors so I'm at a loss as to what to do next.
EDIT:
I have managed to replicate the issue locally by going all the way back to build tools (28.0.3) and running aapt2 dump badging /path/to/my/app.apk
Unsure if this is an AWS issue where they're using an extremely old (6 years) version of build tools but with no way to update it I guess I have to wait or open a support ticket with AWS. I can't be the only person having this issue unless I'm the only person using device farm for Android testing.

Ever end up resolving this? Encountering same thing

Hope this helps - Amazon looks like it already installs the app, and you can point wdio/appium with:
"appium:appPackage": "com.example.app",  // Replace with your app's package name
"appium:appActivity": "com.example.app.MainActivity",  // Replace with your app's main activity

I never solved it in the end, gave up and went on to other things. I debugged and logged out so much of the device farm environment, force installed build tools 33.0.0 and even 34.0.0 same issue like it was ignoring my overrides and using really old build tools.
The capabilities I used were:
platformName: 'Android', 'appium:automationName': 'UiAutomator2',
'appium:deviceName': process.env.DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_NAME,
'appium:app': process.env.DEVICEFARM_APP_PATH
May try the ones that worked for you and report back. Thanks.

Can't believe how undocumented all of this stuff is to be honest. But yeah, launching by package and activity is working perfectly now in my ci/cd pipeline
